# Zend Framework 1.11 really slow.. Why?

Tags: zend-framework, profiling, performance, zend-autoloader

I Use Zend Framework 1.11 and this is really slow for me.

I Have a button and then, when I click on it, that perform an ajax request.

The response is Small. I Return a

> Hello World

The response time is 125ms.

To much for this small ajax request.

Anybody have an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well , it shouldn't take that much , could you please post the code and your os information ,

but i suggest to 
**run xdebug profiler**

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2899

http://www.slideshare.net/samkeen/profiling-php-with-xdebug-webgrind

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anything from:

- Locale
- Currency
- Db

Also try using optcode cache (like zend accelerator). ZF can be slow on PCs with low IO performance while it loads many small files.

We have 125ms response on server for our ecommerce with hardcore optimalization (but without cache).

Comment: For the moment, this is a empty project. only an Ajax request.

Comment: I try it on my Shared Hoster and this is the same thing. 125 ms for this small request. I don't have any control on the shared host. Any other suggest ?

Comment: Try any of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708754/optimising-the-zend-framework/4718334#4718334